# What's the correct csv format for MMQGIS Join by attribute?

Tags: qgis, csv

When trying to join attributes from CSV-file with MMQGIS, I currently get the error message:

---

File inaccessible or in unrecognized CSV format /Netzplanung/Truck_park/trkbuspk15_2.csv

---

Tried with semicolons and commas as seperators, didn't work. Using Qgis master 1.9.0, MMQGIS 2012.12.07. Anybody got an idea?

Attached sample csv file (semicolons as separators)
[sample file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/89290292/trkbuspk15_4.csv)

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Maybe it is missing the header or quoting or is inconsistent or ...

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx - just added

Comment: Try opening the CSV in Notepad or similar program and delete the blank line at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the problem could be related to the way your operating system understands the decimal separator.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the first line tells me that you have only 3 fields. But in the second line you have a number that has a comma separating values (decimal separator?). A csv file generically delimits the information in the table with  commas.  I modified your original file

[image]

First I replaced the original comma to a point, the all the semicolons to commas. Now I am able to open your file in a spreadsheet and look at a table with 3 columns.

If the comma in the original values is a decimal separator you have to tell your operating system that you want the separator to be a point. I know that it could be confusing, but it is the only way your file could be interpreted correctly. Do not forget to include your csvt file also. If the comma is athousands separator, jus get rid of it,

hope it helps

Gerardo

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data, Did you included the csvt file declaring your field types? look at this:

http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/

It does work when you are making a join via the layer properties...

Hope it helps

Comment: .csvt is a GDAL-specific solution. I don't think MMQGIS would recognize it.